# Accents in tabular environment is not well showing

Tags: tables, accents

in this table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    Á      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Á\\(Here is the problem)\end{tabular} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent that the accent of capital A (Á) in the second column appears properly

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on `booktabs` which will fix this for you automatically.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    Á & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Á\\(Here is the problem)\end{tabular}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```